# Having Issues Returning A Value Based on a Hash Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm having difficulty accessing a particular value from a Koala `GraphCollection` object
 (represented as a Ruby hash). I am successfully returning the following data from a Facebook test user (This is a page object connected with the User):

```
[{"name"=>"Product Name", "access_token"=>"--Access Token Goes Here--", 
"category"=>"Baby goods/kids goods", "id"=>"244624772329824", "perms"=>["ADMINISTER", 
"EDIT_PROFILE", "CREATE_CONTENT", "MODERATE_CONTENT", "CREATE_ADS", "BASIC_ADMIN"]}]
```

What I would like to do is present the ID Value in my Rails view be accessing a class method from the view. The method in the model looks like this:

```
accounts = facebook.get_connection("me", "accounts")
accounts.each { |f| f['id'] }
```

The code in the view simply calls the method:

```
<%= current_user.my_page_id %>
```

The result of this attempt is simply returning the full data collection outlined above. I've tried several other Ruby Hash techniques, but most result in "Can't Convert String to Integer".

I'm using Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9.3p125.

Thanks much!

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace for the error and tell us which line it's pointing to. Hard to debug this issue without it.

Comment: @Ryan - thanks for the feedback. The code above wasn't actually returning an error, but the output was undesirable. Just needed a nudge to get working with the hash properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only ever expecting a single id from that method, change it to

```
def my_page_id
  facebook.get_connection("me","accounts").first["id"]
end
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks Zach. And I think that's just the nudge I needed. I don't expect it to return a single ID each time, but I'll go ahead and take a shot at handling multiple.

Comment: You should probably also think about what should happen when it doesn't return anything, or if there is some other error. I haven't used Koala myself, so I can't tell you what all the exceptions might be.